# Rotate image, but keep flexbox sizing

Tags: css, flexbox, rotation, transform, image-rotation

I'm created a simple flexbox layout of a header, image and a footer. Header and footer are just one line of text, while the image takes the as much space as possible, centered. I need to rotate the image, while keeping the layout like this. Is it possible in pure CSS?

Here are some images.

Image before rotation, correct layout:

[image]

Image after rotation, incorrectly sized:

[image]

How it should look like after rotation:

[image]

I understand why it the image is too small after rotation - it uses the box before rotation and just applies rotation on it. Is it possible to somehow use the image box calculation after transforming it? Or is there any other CSS way to achieve this effect reliably?

Here's the snippet:

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top,
.bottom {
    background-color: #444;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

.image {
    flex-grow: 1;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    min-height: 0;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    object-position: center center;
    rotate: 270deg;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Rotate</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="container">
            <header class="top">Top</header>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/sPTMbpF/panorama.jpg" class="image">
            <footer class="bottom">Bottom</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this would require re-flowing the document, which is something the rendering engines don't do without a command, which is beyond the capabilities of CSS.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin in my case it would be easier in theory, as I'm using object-fit, so it would be enough to rotate the contents of the image and then scale it inside. I'm aware that doing it like this is not possible in CSS (yet?) though. Something like object-rotate would be perfect if it existed.

Comment: but what is the use case of it? why are trying to make it this much complicated, when you can only have a 100vh container, and the image in the middle taking 100% of the width?

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan the image is not always taking 100% of the width. It's either width or height.

Comment: @RoboRobok before I answer, are you forced to use a vertical image?

Comment: if you are not forced, here is what you can do: https://codepen.io/arash__jb/pen/YzdrBRd

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan Please skip this question.

Comment: I am having trouble telling what the actual use case would be here as well. Your given example only appears to make sense, because in the _original_ image, the Eiffel Tower is "on its side" already. But is that actually the situation you will be dealing with here - that the orientation of the _motive_ is basically "off" to begin with? [...]

Comment: [...] Because otherwise, I can hardly see much sense in just rotating an image willy-nilly, simply based on whether it is portrait or landscape. If you _have_ a special situation where this is not relevant (because what your images contain can be "looked at" from whatever angle, and still will make the same amount of sense), then you should mention that

Comment: @CBroe say what? You noticed that the original image is rotated wrong, didn't you?

Comment: _"You noticed that the original image is rotated wrong, didn't you?"_ - yes, that's why I _said_ exactly that :-) The _question_ is how come this is a case you need to handle in CSS in the first place? _Why_ do you need to work with images that are so obviously "stored wrong"? What is preventing whoever will be using this (with a dynamic image selection, I suppose?), to use a _proper_ image in the first place? IMHO you are trying to fix a problem at your end here, that _should_ not be handled there in the first place ...